# FileUpload using AutoIT

Tags: javascript, selenium, file-upload, vbscript, autoit

I'm trying to upload a file using AutoIT. The windows popup got opened, but the file has not been uploaded. Not sure what i'm doing wrong here

AutoIT Script:

```
Local $UploadWindow
Local $Firefox
Local $Chrome
Local $IE

Local $path = $CmdLine[1]
Local $browser = $CmdLine[2]

If $browser = "Firefox" then
    $Firefox = WinWait("File upload", "", 5)
ElseIf $browser = "Chrome" then
    $Chrome = WinWait("Open", "", 5)
ElseIf $browser = "IE" then
    $IE = WinWait("Choose File to Upload", "", 5)
EndIf

If WinExists($Firefox) then
  $UploadWindow = "File upload"
ElseIf WinExists($Chrome) then
  $UploadWindow = "Open"
ElseIf WinExists($IE) then
  $UploadWindow = "Choose File to Upload"
Else
  $UploadWindow = ""
EndIf

If $UploadWindow <> "" then
  ControlFocus($UploadWindow,"","Edit1")
  ControlsetText($UploadWindow,"","Edit1",$path)
  ControlClick($UploadWindow,"","Button1")
EndIf
```

JavaScript

```js
public void fileUpload(){
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(.exe file path + " " + .jpg image file path + getParams.getEnvPerValue("BROWSER_TYPE"));
}

getParams.getEnvPerValue("BROWSER_TYPE")) //This will read from the Properties file.
BROWSER_TYPE = Chrome //or IE or Firefox
```

Note: `<input>` tag is not visible for the file upload button. Actually, File Upload button is customized. So i'm not able to use the `sendkeys()` method 
 [Fileupload using Sendkeys() method](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17020/upload-a-file-in-selenium-webdriver-using-sendkeys)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it is a window pop-up? Can you post an image & code which triggers Upload?

Comment: Yes, it is a windows popup...For testing, u can create an Html element and perform click action on that webelement

Comment: You can create like this <input type="file" id="test" name="pic" /> and save this as an .html file

Comment: I had created similar thing for uploading document and your autoIT script looks similar; although mine was a simple script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBScript Autoit programming file upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281875/vbscript-autoit-programming-file-upload)